# Expected value of $X$ if $(X, Y, Z)$ has a uniform distribution on the plane $X+Y+Z = 1$

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

Recently I got asked this question during an interview: If a point (X, Y, Z) has a uniform distribution on the plane X+Y+Z = 1, what's E[X] ?

I tried assuming $f_X,_Y,_Z(x,y,z) = c$, and thus $f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-z-x} cdydz$. But solving this gives me $f_X(x) = c(\frac{1}{2}-x)$, which is negative when $x > \frac{1}{2}$. This is not right as x can definitley take values larger than $\frac{1}{2}$. So what did I do wrong there?

Sorry if the way I formulate the problem is not clear or precise enough but this was all the information given to me.

Update: I realized the upper bound I wrote of the integral for $f_X(x)$ is not correct. It should be $f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-z-x} cdydz$, where $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-z-x} c dydzdx = 1$. Solving for c I got c = 6, and $E[X] =  \int_{0}^{1}xf_X(x)dx = \frac{1}{4}$. However according to the hint from @awkward, $E[X] + E[Y] + E[Z] = 1$, and I believe due to the symmetry of the distributions of X, Y, Z we should have $E[X] = E[Y] = E[Z] = \frac{1}{3}$? This confuses me as I don't know which answer is correct and why the other one isn't.

Comment: Hint: E(X) + E(Y) + E(Z) = E(X+Y+Z) = 1

Comment: Awkward's hint is good, but what does "uniform distribution" mean here? Maybe your interviewers meant "symmetric" ?

Comment: Uniform seems very odd. How can you have a uniform distribution over an unbounded region?

Comment: Possibly the first octant $X, Y, Z > 0$ was also meant?

Comment: @awkward thank you for the hint. Does that imply E(X) = E(Y) = E(Z) = 1/3 since they are 'symmetric' ?

Comment: @ConnorHarris  Sorry for the confusion! The region should be triangle with the 3 vertices of (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0) and (1, 0, 0) and therefore is in the first octant.

Comment: @YilieMa In answer to your question, yes, since X, Y, and Z are symmetric, their expected values are equal.

Comment: @awkward Thanks! But could you enlighten me what I did wrong using the definition of expected values and pdf as I showed above? I think the math is correct so the problem should be in the setup?